# Semialgebraic Morse-Sard Theorem - why are the critical points of a semi-algebraic map again semi-algebraic?

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

> 2.5.12 **Exercise** (Semi-algebraic Morse-Sard theorem)
>
> Let $f:M\to N$ be a $C^\infty$ semi-algebraic map between semi-algebraic submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$, respectively. Set $$C = \{x\in M; \operatorname{rank} df_x < \dim N\},$$ $$S=\{y\in N; y=f(x), x\in C\}.$$
> Then $S$ is a semi-algebraic set and $\dim S<\dim N$.

I was reading this theorem from Benedetti and Risler book, and I cannot understand why is $C$ a semialgebraic set. Is the rank of a linear transformation a semialgebraic map? I can't see why.

Comment: The condition of rank smaller than a number is equivalent to all [minor determinants of that size being zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#:~:text=Determinantal%20rank%20%E2%80%93%20size%20of%20largest%20non%2Dvanishing%20minor).

Comment: So I can express the set $C$ as $\{A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}): det^{-1}(B) = 0, \forall B \hspace{0.2mm} \text{submatrix of} \hspace{0.2mm} A\}$? I still can't see why this is a semialgebraic set.

Comment: Please note that [images of text and mathematical expressions are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). I've converted your image to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) - please keep this in mind for the future. Separately, it would be helpful if you could add the source of this question with an [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that a matrix is of rank $<n$ is that the determinants of all $n\times n$ minors vanish. Since the determinant is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, this is a collection of polynomial conditions on the entries of the matrix.

As the matrix $df$ has semi-algebraic entries because the derivative of a semi-algebraic function is semi-algebraic (where it exists), the determinant of any minor of $df$ is again semi-algebraic, being a polynomial in semi-algebraic functions. Therefore the condition that $\operatorname{rank} df_x < \dim N$ is semi-algebraic.